# How to prevent Accessibility action from propagating to the operating system (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility

I have an application that enables blind users to read newspapers. I'm using SwiftUI and the `.accessibilityAction(.magicTap)` to start/stop text to speech. The problem is that if Accessibility focus is on any other element than the one showing the text, the magic tap gesture propagates to the operating system starting/stopping speech in some other application.

Does anyone have a sane solution that does not involve adding the magic tap modifier to all UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into grouping multiple UI elements into a single accessibility element with `.accessibilityElement()` and then apply the `.accessibilityAction(.magicTap)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/capsule/accessibilityelement(children:)/